# Calling ActionResult method from the View using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I am calling my action result method using this:

```
var url= "/Example/Controler/1/Action";

$("<form action='"+url+"'></form>").submit();
```

But the action Method is not called...
I have also tried this

```
$.post(url, function (data) {});
```

And this works, we call the controller, but then the page doesn't refresh...

My action method looks like this:

```
public ActionResult DoStuff(int Id)
    {   
     .....
     return   RedirectToAction("index", new { Id });
    }
```

Comment: Are you actually submitting data? (is the `<form>` required?) Also, is your action decorated with `HttpPost` by chance?

Comment: In $.post() method success function, you have to update page content

Comment: @ Brad Christie nope no httppost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Ajax function as follows :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controler/Action",
    data: { 'Id': groupId },
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (result) {
       //do the necessary updations
    },
    error: function (result) {
    }
});
```

You can also try form submission as follows :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.GET))
{
       // do your html
       <input type="submit" value="save"/>
}
```

Comment: //do the necessary updations = document.location.reload(true);